# $\Pr(Z > z) = 1 - \Pr(Z < z)$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, z-score

I do not get it: why do we subtract the $Z$ score from 1 when $P(Z > z)$?

i.e. $P(Z > z) = 1 - P(Z < z)$. Please give an example with graphical representation.

I was calculating the power of 2 tailed null hypothesis test, and for the upper Tail / right tail the probability was $P(Z>2)$, so there I was supposed to do this $P(Z>2)=1-P(Z<2)$, I want to know the reason.

Comment: **NB:** Take care with the inequalities, because the equations you have written are not generally true.  Look at Tim's answer for statements that *are* true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probabilities sum to unity. If $Z$ lies on a real line then then it can be either smaller or equal to $z$, or greater then $z$. So probability that $Z > z$ must be complement of probability that $Z  \le z$, i.e. $1-P(Z\le z)$.